# 19.04 on starting freezes on Ubuntu logo

Tags: drivers, 18.04, grub2, upgrade

After updating Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 19.04 on starting it freezes on Ubuntu logo and rapidly the dots are running. After trying GRUB settings change to `nomodeset` to skip the driver loading it generates an error saying:

```
hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: unable to bind the codec
```

[image: boot messages]